# Radio buttons in a Bootstrap .form-horizontal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to get sane behavior out of Bootstrap with radio buttons inside a `.form-horizontal`.

The problem is getting the radio buttons and their labels to line up while also aligning with the rest of the form. The best I've managed is this:

```
    <legend>New user</legend>
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="#" class="form-horizontal" id="new_user" method="post">

        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="user_affiliation">Affiliation</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input id="user_affiliation" name="user[affiliation]" size="30" type="text" />
            </div>
          </div>

        <div class="control-group">
          <div clas="controls">
            <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input id="user_role_managing_editor" name="user[role]" type="radio" value="Managing editor">
                Managing editor
              </label>
              <label>
                <input id="user_role_area_editor" name="user[role]" type="radio" value="Area editor">
                Area editor
              </label>
              <label>
                <input id="user_role_author_or_referee" name="user[role]" type="radio" value="Author or referee">
                Author/referee
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div style="text-align: center;">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Register" />
        </div>

    </form>
```

Which gets me this:[image]

As you can see, the radio-buttons are out of whack with the rest of the form. They ought to line up vertically with the text-field, or do something more sensible than hug the left as if this were a `.form-inline`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

No hacks!, Using bootstrap2:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label"> User role</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="user[role]" id="user_role_managing_editor" value="Managing editor" checked>
      Managing editor
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="user[role]" id="user_role_area_editor" value="Area editor">
      Area editor
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="user[role]" id="user_role_author_or_referee" value="Author or referee">
      Author/referee
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GX6q4/1/

Update: Here is the Bootstrap3 version:

```
<legend>New user</legend>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="#" class="form-horizontal" id="new_user" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="user_affiliation">Affiliation</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="user_affiliation" name="user[affiliation]" size="30" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">User role</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="user[role]" id="user_role_managing_editor" value="Managing editor" checked>Managing editor
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="user[role]" id="user_role_area_editor" value="Area editor">Area editor
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="user[role]" id="user_role_author_or_referee" value="Author or referee">Author/referee
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/24sx72mn/1/

Bootstrap 4 version:

```
<legend>New user</legend>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="#" id="new_user" method="post">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="user_affiliation">Affiliation</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" id="user_affiliation" name="user[affiliation]" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">User role</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="form-check">

        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="user[role]" id="user_role_managing_editor" value="Managing editor" checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="user_role_managing_editor">
          Managing editor
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">

        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="user[role]" id="user_role_area_editor" value="Area editor">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="user_role_area_editor">
          Area editor
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">

        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="user[role]" id="user_role_author_or_referee" value="Author or referee">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="user_role_author_or_referee">
          Author/referee
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p8wyd7s8/1/

Answer (score 1):

No hacks, you just need to use the Bootstrap grid system (col-xx-x classes), for example:

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label for="txt_web" class="col-lg-3 control-label">xxx</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="txt_web" id="txt_web"  />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" >
    <label for="txt_web" class="col-lg-3 control-label">xxx</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="radio">...</div>
        ...

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some style for your `radio` class,

```
.radio {
    margin-left:180px;
}
```

Check [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ND5TT/).

Comment: Yea, I know I can hack it, but it'd be way better to do it the bootstrap way. Surely they didn't just forget to accommodate radio buttons in horizontal forms, there must be a way of marking things up to get reasonable results.

Comment: @Jonathan In Twitter Bootstrap 3, we can group them using some `grid` classes. But in Bootstrap 2x, you should hack it.

Comment: `class = "offset2"` it is... grim.